# How to make 2 column portfolio page, left is navigation, right is image display when image gets hovered on the left nav words

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, navigation

I am making a portfolio website and I am trying to mimic this effect http://xavierbourdil.com/ I am able to create the hover effect with words appearing on the right, but if I try this with Images it won't let me place it in the right side div. Can anyone please help me with a simple html/css solution?

**html**

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a class="galleryhover" href="#menu1">SOLAR</a><img class="right" src="img/green.jpg" alt=""></li>
    <li><a class="galleryhover" href="#menu2">INK CHEF</a><img src="img/gray.jpg" alt=""></li>
    <li><a class="galleryhover" href="#menu3">BRANDING</a><img src="img/yellow.jpg" alt=""></li>
    <li><a class="galleryhover" href="#menu4">POSTERS</a></li>
    <li><a class="galleryhover" href="#menu5">LAYOUT</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

**css**

```
container {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 100px auto;
    width: 800px;
    height: 500px;
}

.container img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -60;
}

.container li img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 800px;
    z-index: -50;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}

li a:hover {
    background: #eee;
}

li a:hover + img {
    left: 0px;
}

.galleryright {
    right: -700px;
}
```

Possibility #2:
**html**
I have tried this before, but I need it to work with images instead of the words that are ('') next to hover on mouseover.... Can the script be altered for me to put an image in the onmouseover? I have tried multiple things already. Any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance guys!

```
<div id="content">
    Stuff should be placed here.
</div>

<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<ul>
    <li onmouseover="hover('Apples are delicious')">Apple</li>
    <li onmouseover="hover('oranges are healthy')">Orange</li>
    <li onmouseover="hover('Candy is the best')">Candy</li>
</ul>

<script>
    function hover(description) {
        console.log(description);
        document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = description;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Are you trying to do this with pure css ?

Comment: Hi Amin Meyghani, whatever is the simplest way to do it...

Comment: Can you paste in what you have tried ?

Comment: You can actually post in code in the question itself. I put your code in your question so other people can easily see your question/code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this with JavaScript is to attach a listener on the nav, pick the one that was hovered, pick the src value and change the src of the image on the right side

Example: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q0pq8tjt/)

**html**

```
<article>
  <section>
    <ul class="portfolio-nav" id="js-portfolio-links">
      <li><a data-img-src="http://placehold.it/400x150" href="">First Image</a></li>
      <li><a data-img-src="http://placehold.it/350x150" href="">Second Image</a></li>
    </ul>
  </section>
  <section class="portfolio-img">
    <div class="img-placeholder">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/400x150" id="js-img-placeholder">
    </div>
  </section>
</article>
```

**js**

```
var links = document.getElementById('js-portfolio-links');
var placeholder = document.getElementById('js-img-placeholder');
links.addEventListener('mouseover', function(e) {

  if (e.target && e.target.nodeName === 'A') {
    var srcPath = e.target.getAttribute('data-img-src');
    placeholder.src = srcPath;
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so so much! Do you think that I will have sizing issues with the images on different monitors? since the images will be a specific size on the right... Again THANK YOU!!!!!!

Comment: I have one more question... How do I get the Images to crossfade in this case? Since I can't specify on <img>. Thanks again!

Comment: Thinking on top of my head I think you would have to load the images first and then use the links to identify which image should have opacity of 1. Then with css animation on opacity you can make them fade in and out. Btw, if my answer to your first question helped, please accept the answer.

Comment: Hi Armin, I accepted and upvoted, this is my first time using this forum.. sorry about that! My problem is putting the properties for the images, by loading the images first do you mean in js? This website does what I want but I can't apply it since I can't put a class on data-img-src http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/cfimg/